# Taking snapshot Vlc.DotNet.Form to variable Bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

We need to processing image in C# from UDP video stream. in project we can get image and save it to Path With vlcControl. We need to have this image in a variable and not inside a file on the hard drive.
Please see my code below:

```
vlcControl1.TakeSnapshot(@"D:\a.jpg", 600, 400);
```

Now we need to have an address in memory or override a method to solve the problem.

We tried to create an address in memory and another override a method TakeSnapshot

Comment: I don't know about the library but you can use memory mapped files to avoid writing on the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In libvlc3/LibVLCSharp3, there is no way to get a snapshot in memory.
If you want all frames in memory, you could consider this option instead : https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/tree/master/PreviewThumbnailExtractor

In LibVLC4, still in prerelease, there is an APi for that :
https://mfkl.github.io/libvlc/2020/07/23/Gracefully-surfacing-asynchronous-C-APIs-to-.NET.html

From that blog post, you can see the following lines used to create a snapshot :

```cs
using var media = new Media(libVLC, new Uri("C:\\Path\\To\\Videos\\big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mkv"));
using var thumbnail = await media.GenerateThumbnail(time: 200, 
                                speed: ThumbnailerSeekSpeed.Fast, 
                                width: 200, 
                                height: 200, 
                                crop: false, 
                                pictureType: PictureType.Argb);
```